# Raster map tips in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, maptips

Is there a way to enable map tips for a DEM raster layer? I want to hover over a raster and get the values.

I usually do this in ArcMap and I am trying to learn if it is possible in QGIS.

Comment: To display cell value at the mouse tip, you can use [Value Tool](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/) plugin. (NB the value is shown in another panel, not at the cursor point.)

Comment: Thank you @Kazuhito! This is close to the functionality that I was looking for.

Comment: @Kazuhito please post your comment as an answer so this question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Value Tool](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/) plugin which displays the cell value as you hover your mouse over it.

Unfortunately the value is shown in another panel, not at the cursor point as you used to see in ArcGIS' Map Tips.

Answer (score 2):

I used this formula for the map tip on a DEM layer:

```
[% round(raster_value(@layer_id, 1, @layer_cursor_point), 2) %] m
```

It takes the current layer, band 1, at the mouse cursor position and returns the raw value at that position, rounds it to two decimal places, and displays it with an `m` following it for metres.

This allows me to hover anywhere on the raster layer and the elevation in metres at that point is displayed in the map tip.